# Powershell - Add-ItemVersion

Tags: powershell-extensions

I want to create a new language version via Powershell (the item has no versions yet) but I'm not able to do so via Powershell... I'm not getting an error but the version is also NOT created

This is my snippet:

```
$path = "master:/sitecore/content/test"
$item = Get-Item -Path $path
Add-ItemVersion -Item $item -IfExist Append -TargetLanguage "fr-BE"
```

The item "sitecore/content/test" does exist but has no versions.

Comment: Have a look at this issue to see if it addresses your situation. https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/1162

Answer (score 2):

Never had issues adding version with pse. Usually going with *Add-ItemLanguage* directly :

`Add-ItemLanguage -Path $path -Language "en" -TargetLanguage "fr" -IfExist Skip`

Comment: This solution worked for me !  Many Thanks